# use Tor to redirect terminal command using HTTPTunnelPort

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ip, tor

I am trying to redirect terminal commands through Tor. However i get the following error when I want to check my public IP address.

```
$ curl https://ipinfo.io/ip
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:9051
```

I have set proxy for terminal using these commands

```
$ export http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:9051'    
$ export https_proxy='https://127.0.0.1:9051'
```

I have appended "HTTPTunnelPort 9051" to /etc/tor/torrc and restarted Tor service.

I have also checked to make sure 9051 port is open and listening.

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN 
tor       10757      debian-tor    6u  IPv4 120224      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9050 (LISTEN)
tor       10757      debian-tor    7u  IPv4 120225      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9051 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl has socks5 compatibility, here's a Bash script I use for downloading over Tor with Curl...

**`~/bin/torrific-curl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_address="${1:?No address supplied}"
_location="${2}"
_socks5_port='9050'

_cmd=('curl' '--socks5' "localhost:${_socks5_port}" '--socks5-hostname' "localhost:${_socks5_port}" '-s' "${_address}")

((${#_location})) && {
  ${_cmd[@]} -o "${_location}"
} || {
  ${_cmd[@]}
}
```

**Setup**

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/torrific-curl
```

**Usage**

```
torrific-curl 'https://ipinfo.io/ip'

## Or with output file...

torrific-curl\
  'https://ipinfo.io/ip'\
  "/tmp/torrific-ip_$(date +'%Y-%m_%d-%T').txt"
```

... it's kinda *hit-&-miss* on what applications play nice with Tor's `HTTPTunnelPort`, but I'm willing to swing through again with an edit to this answer if further details are provided.